# What makes the entire room on fire in Inferno Butcher?

Tags: diablo-iii

We're trying to beat the Butcher on Inferno, and towards the end of the fight the entire room is on fire at once, so nowhere is safe to stand and we all die.

It's always happened around 25% of his life, but sometimes higher and other times lower.

Does the entire room start on fire based on the Butcher's hp, or based on time?

We're trying to figure out if we need more dps, or hp/fire resist.

Comment: DPS. 3 min soft enrage (at 1:30 there starts to be 2 panels lit up simultaneously, 2:00 3 panels, 2:30 4 panels (out of 6 iirc))

Comment: @hkf You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's effectively a 'soft enrage' - if you're taking too long on the fight, progressively more of the floor will light up until eventually the entire room is one giant cascading field of burny death.

Every time you have to revive is damage time lost, so first aim to.. well, not die. (Vastly harder than it sounds, I know, but it's still the truth!) Stocking up on ways to deal damage even when you have to run (the Wizard's Hydra, for example) can help make the difference as well.

Comment: But where to hide when the whole floor is fire?

Comment: @Fredy31: You can't. That's the point. You need to kill him *before* this happens. If this happens, then you need more DPS and possibly better gear before you can kill him.

Comment: Oh that's not going to be funny when I'll get there. I'm more tank than DPS.