# Which bosses have an enrage timer and what are their effects?

Tags: diablo-iii

We already know that [the Butcher sets the whole room on fire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/70506/23609) if you fail to kill him in 3 minutes.

Are just the end-of-act bosses that possess an enrage timer? 
What are their effects? Is the timing the same for every one of them? Does the timer depend on the group size?

Comment: Here is a [timer](http://diablo3enrage.com).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since patch 1.0.4 Elite packs no longer enrage, and all boss enrage timers only take effect on inferno difficulty.

**Boss Enrage Timers**

*Boss enrage timers appear to be specific for Inferno difficulty only*

The Butcher - will set fire to all of the platforms in his chamber simultaneously if you fail to kill him within three minutes.

Ghom - will begin spawning 'Gas Clouds' more frequently after four minutes.

Zoltun Kulle - will enrage, using his 'Ceiling Collapse' ability more frequently, and for more damage after three minutes.

Belial - Enrages after three minutes in phase 3, increasing the number of green pools spawned, which will be spawned across the entire platform.

Cydaea - will enrage after four minutes, causing spiderlings to spawn more frequently.

Rakanoth - will become more aggressive after three minutes.

Comment: Does the enrage timer appear on all difficulties or just inferno? If the boss or elite mob is enraged, are there any visual indications that tell you so?

Comment: @ThierryLam elites that have enraged have a skull/crossed bones above their head with a red background to it as per [this picture](http://i.imgur.com/Xai1l.jpg)

Comment: @ThierryLam I have updated my answer detailing this more clearly, and added the incoming changes for the 1.0.3 patch.

Comment: What about enrage timer on champions and elite mobs? Are they on inferno only too?

Comment: @ThierryLam no, they're all difficulties I believe, certainly Nightmare, Hell and Inferno (the screenshot is of a level 55 in Hell)

Comment: I just have to add, Belial's enrage means he will constantly spam the exploding pools, and also at a far greater rate.  Making his fight almost impossible on inferno once he enrages.

Comment: Are there any details on what exactly "Out of Time" does?

Comment: @bwarner tooltip simply says "Combat against an Elite monster has grown more difficult, you are now taking damage over time". However, in this affect seems to ramp up over time, resulting in the initial ticks not hitting for a great amount but steadily growing the longer you stay alive against the enrage. [Video demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSnkwiLalF0).

Comment: Sounds like the enrage timer for elites is going away in 1.04

Comment: once the patch is released I will update my answer

Comment: @kalina Could you update your post with 2.0.1 (post Reaper) enrage timer information?

Comment: Belial's enrage is the fourth wave of pool spawns, for people wanting an in-game cue to track enrage timers.

Comment: Are you sure Cydaea has an enrage?  She's not listed on the [boss enrage list when they moved enrages to Torment 1+](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/12671560/patch-201-now-live-2-25-2014##Bosses).

Answer (score 5):

I've hit enrage timers on Blue and Yellow mobs before.
As soon as timer hits, the mobs did instant/constant AOE damage. I was playing on inferno, and the effect was hitting me for 5k dps

I'm not sure of the time it took for these mobs, but I do know it was at least 3 min. I would say it felt close to 10 min, but game time always seems longer. It was a mob of 3, for the record

I doubt these have to do with enrage, but I know that if you haven't killed Diablo within like 2 or 3 minutes he does that colorful purple blast that hits pretty hard. My friend said Azmodan's Hell's grasp type attack starts covering the entire map after 3 or 4 (reported for inferno).

Comment: The champions on inferno do enrage if you don't kill them fast enough. They get a red icon over their head, and just being in their presence will start doing damage to you every second. It starts off small (around 1k) and will rapidly increase in damage (One death of mine was due to 8k ticks)

Comment: @Twong Hell's grasp is the pool of blood?

Comment: @QAppei yes, Hell's Grasp is the 'defile' style effect, the growing pools.

Answer (score 0):

All bosses in Inferno difficulty have soft enrage timers.

Most elites in hell, all in inferno, also have soft enrage timers.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Indeed, all it does is acknowledge that bosses and perhaps elites, have enrage timers.

Comment: @fbueckert There have also been reports of Belial and Azmodan not having an enrage timer, so this answer, unless supported by further proofs, may be outright wrong.

Comment: @Kappei Just to add it took me 6 minutes to kill Belial and never noticed any enrage timer.